# Looping through all select elements with JavaScript Prototype library

Tags: javascript, loops, prototypejs, html-select

How can I (if it is possible) use the Prototype library to loop through all select elements on a page and access the element? In the documentation I found easily shortcuts for referencing elements with certain ids, class names etc. but no reference for elements with certain tag names.

If this is not possible with Prototype, an example with JQuery or another JS Library would be appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check out the first example [in this page](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/dollar-dollar/):

```
$$('select').each(function() {
    //
});
```

Essentially, the `$$` function expects a CSS selector, and a tag name is a perfectly valid selector.

Comment: You can reference the items which you iterate adding a parameter to the function:
each(function(item) {
item.doSomething()...

Answer (score 4):

A jQuery example, for variety:

```
$('select').each(function() {
    var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
    alert('Value: ' + selectedOption.val() + ' Text: ' + selectedOption.text());
});
```

That will iterate over all `select`s in the page, and alert the text and value of the selected `option` on each `select`.